# Collab button is not showing after Unity start

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2018.4.29.

When Unity is booted, in the console, I have no errors at the start. After editing a script and saving, the compiler starts, I get a bunch of errors, which are false interpretations. My way of solving is to Reimport All assets, then Collab starts to be visible again and the errors disappear from the console. I can pull the changes and everything works.
But it can't be that every time I open Unity (with changes made to Collab) I need to reimport all assets. Especially since we have some legacy 3d models that take my laptop to import our project for over an hour..

Somebody already had this kinda question:
[Unity Collaborate not working (button not showing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62577284/5486606)
But there was no answer to it, so I had to make a new post.

Comment: Since you linked the other question: Are there any compiler errors?

Answer (score 1):

Updating Visual Studio (to 8.8.3(16)) fixed the problem. :)